# SlideUp/Slidedown - Button is child of closing div and doesn'trigger parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slidedown, slideup

I have a little slideup, slidedown system. width some fading in it. Everything works fine, except from the slide up function. That does not seem to change the display back to none.

Here is a Fiddle:
[Slide Up/Down Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wimvandurme/szb5ydty/2/)

**HTML**

```
   <div class="standorte-m-wrapper">
      <div class="panel-m up">
        <div class="pan-item-m">
          <div class="adres-wrap-m">
            <button  class="mobile" data-ajaxFile="0">ZU-1
            <i class="icon-down-open-2 iset"></i></button>
        </div> 
    </div><!--
    --><div class="pan-item-m">
        <div class="adres-wrap-m">
            <button  class="mobile" data-ajaxFile="1">ZU-2<i class="icon-down-open-2 iset"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="pan-item-m">
        <div class="adres-wrap-m">
            <button  class="mobile" data-ajaxFile="2">BS<i class="icon-down-open-2 iset"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="pan-item-m">
        <div class="adres-wrap-m">
            <button  class="mobile" data-ajaxFile="3">LU<i class="icon-down-open-2 iset"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="open" class="panel-m down">
    <div class="close-button">
        <a href="#" id="close-m" class="close"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="php-content-m"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $('.adres-wrap-m > button').on('click', function() {
     if ($('.panel-m.up').hasClass('open')) {
     //alert('already open');
     } else {
     $('.panel-m.up').addClass('open');
     $('.standorte-m-wrapper').addClass('expand');
     $('.panel-m.down').slideDown(1000);
     }
     $('#php-content-m').html(ajaxFiles[$(this).attr('data-ajaxFile')]);
     setTimeout(function (){
     $('.panel-m.down div').fadeIn(400);
     }, 500);
     });
     $('#close-m').on('click', function() {
     $('.panel-m.down div').fadeOut(400);
     setTimeout(function (){
     $('.panel-m.up').removeClass('open');
     $('.standorte-m-wrapper').removeClass('expand');
     $('#close-m').parent().css("display", "block");
     $('.pannel-m.down').slideUp(1000);
     }, 500);
     });
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in `$('#close-m').on('click', function()`

Change `$('.pannel-m.down').slideUp(1000);` to `$('.panel-m.down').slideUp(1000);`

Worked for me

Comment: My goooooooodddd. That 's what you get after a while. Lookin over the most stupid thing. Thx

Comment: Happens to everyone ;) Can you accept this as the answer, please?

Comment: I had to Wait 5 min. That s how fast you were :)